# What is the probability? Two players dealt from 52-card deck. Both get straights!

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, gambling

A standard $52$-card deck:

Player $1$ (is dealt first, only $2$ players in the "deal"), he looks at his cards, goes all in.  He has a straight with high-card $H_1$.

Player $2$ (is dealt second), he doesn't look at his cards, and matches the all in.

$(1)$ What is the straight-up probability Player 1 will win the hand, with no other information.  How is that probability adjusted based on the value of his high-card?  Say $H_1 = 7$ versus $H_1 =$ Jack.

$(2)$ What is the straight-up probability Player 2 draws a straight, GIVEN Player 1 has already drawn a straight?  What is the probability of having the same high card $(H_2 == H_1)?$  $(H_2 < H_1)?$  $(H_2 > H_1)?$  What is the probability of $(H_2 > H_1)$ by exactly one number:  e.g, $H_1 = 7, H_2 = 8.$

This actually happened to me.  I was the "lucky" player, Player $1$ was very much nonplussed.

Comment: What [form of poker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker#Variants) are you talking about?  Texas Holdem, $5$-card draw, $5$-card stud, $7$-card stud, or something else?  Your description *appears* to be suggesting a form of straight poker, in which there is just one round of betting before the showdown, after each of the players has simply been dealt $5$ cards, but that's  certainly not clear to me.

Comment: Let's assume 5-cards, classic probability.  We are each dealt 5 cards, the other player cannot see our cards.  I think that is how the actual event degraded, once player 1 got upset.

Comment: I believe we were playing hold-em.  So I would be curious about that probability as well.  Each of us have two cards dealt, he goes all-in, I counter.  So flop, turn, river would be placed.  That would be an alternative probability I would like to see.  I would expect that "joint probability" would be higher than the classic 5-card "final round" we actually did.